How To Determine Specific Index Number To Use With Where-Object?
Can someone explain how you determine what number to place in the brackets “.Properties[??].Value” when using Where-Object. In this attached screenshot, they use [21], but I'm not sure how you determine what number to use.
I now need to pipe to Where-Object, but I don't know how to determine the number to go inside the brackets.
Where-Object Explanation

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
